# How is the right, root, left order traversal called in a binary search tree?

Tags: algorithms, binary-search-trees

In a Binary Search Tree you have the following orders for traversal:

Left, Root, Right is called Inorder (or ascending order).

Root, Left, Right is called Preorder.

Left, Right, Root is called PostOrder.

But how is Right, Root, Left (or descending order) called?

Comment: Reverse inorder probably.

Answer (score 2):

As per wikipedia ([Tree Traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Out-order_(RNL))), it is called ***Out-order traversal***

Though, you could also find reference to *reverse in-order traversal*, which means the same.

Comment: I would immediately understand what "reverse in-order traversal" meant. I'd have no idea what "out-order traversal" meant and this is the first time I've ever heard it.